# Screenshot of Mapbox map without displaying it

Tags: kotlin, screenshot, mapbox-android

I need to display a few previews of addresses on the map on the same screen. To do that I'm going to display `ImageViews` with bitmaps instead of making multiple instances of `MapView`. But for that I need to find a way to capture these bitmaps.

I found `snapshot` function in MapboxMap (https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/issues/6062), but it requires displaying of the map.

```
val position = CameraPosition.Builder()
        .target(addressLatLng)
        .zoom(zoom)
        .build()
mapboxMap.cameraPosition = position

mapboxMap.snapshot { bitmap: Bitmap ->
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
}
```

So, can I take a snapshot of the map without displaying it on the screen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've finally found the solution! The class I needed to use was [MapSnapshotter](https://www.mapbox.com/android-docs/api/map-sdk/5.2.0/com/mapbox/mapboxsdk/snapshotter/MapSnapshotter.html).

```
val width = imageView.width
val height = imageView.height
val location = CameraPosition.Builder()
        .target(LatLng(55.7558, 37.6173))
        .zoom(16.0)
        .build()
val options = MapSnapshotter.Options(width, height)
        .withCameraPosition(location)
MapSnapshotter(context, options).start { snapshot ->
    imageView.setImageBitmap(snapshot.bitmap)
}
```